# U-Substitution for Volume Integral

Tags: integration, volume

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong with the following integral:

Given:
$$ V = \pi\int_1^2 (2-\frac{x}{2})^2 dx$$

Substitutions:
$$ u =  2-\frac{x}{2} $$
$$ du = -\frac{1}{2} dx$$
$$ (-2)du = dx $$

Evaluate new limits of integration:
$$ 2-\frac{1}{2}(1) = \frac{3}{2} $$
$$ 2-\frac{1}{2}(2) = 1 $$

Integrating in terms of u:
$$ \therefore \pi\int_1^2 (2-\frac{x}{2})^2 dx = \pi\int_\frac{3}{2}^1 u^2 (-2)du$$
$$ = -2\pi\left.(\frac{u^3}{3}\right|_\frac{3}{2}^1 )$$
$$ = -2\pi(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{27}{8}) = -2\pi(\frac{8-81}{24}) = -2\pi(\frac{-73}{24})$$
$$ = \frac{73\pi}{12} $$

The correct answer, which I was able to get when I don't use u-substitution, is:
$$ \frac{19\pi}{12} $$

Can someone please point out where I went wrong?

Comment: It is $\frac{1}{3}-\frac{9}{8}$, you forgot to divide by $3$ in the second term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(3/2)^3/3 = 9/8$, not $27/8$.